# Append the updated values of the database to textarea using meteor

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and learning to create web application looking at examples. I want to append the updated values of the database to html textarea.
For example if i update value for key "sensor", the sensor value needs to be appended to textarea. How can I do that using meteor?

Answer (score 0):

You use a handlebars helper and bind changes to your text area to update the field: e.g

*html*

```
<template name="hello">
    <textarea name="address">{{address}}</textarea>
</template
```

*client side js*

```
//Your collection that stores your data
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("mycollection");

//Your handlebars helper to give some data to address
Template.hello.address = function() {
    var address = MyCollection.findOne({name:address});
    if(address) return address.value;
}

//Something to bind changes to your address to your collection
Template.hello.events({
    'change [name=address]' : function(e,cxt) {
        var address = MyCollection.findOne({name:address});
        MyCollection.update(address._id, {$set:{value:e.currentTarget.value}});
    }
});
```

Finally you need something on your server side js too:

```
//The same collection as on your client
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection("mycollection");

//Insert an address on the first time if there is nothing in yet:
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if(!MyCollection.findOne({name:address})) {
        MyCollection.insert({name:address,value:"10 Downing St, London, United Kingdom"});
    }
});
```

Thats the basic gist of it to update a text area when its changed, and to show a value in your template  . When its updated it will also reflect the update across to all tabs/everyone viewing the page.